# Enhancement of unix script

Tags: python, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have an algorithm which mask data of a column entered by user. The below function has been designed for the same. when script was executed , this took around 4 hrs to mask 100 thousands record. client want the same in 10 min. Could you please suggest how can I implement the below so that its performance can be improved. Is there anyway to change function without changing the algorithm.

```
data_mask() {
col_val=$1
l_ret_str=""
l_an=0
l_lp=0
l_mod=0
absnum=0
austart=65
auend=90
aclsize=26
alstart=97
alend=122
nstart=48
nend=57
nclsize=10
l_lp=`expr length "$col_val"`
if [[ $l_lp -ne 0 ]]; then
for i in `eval "echo {1..$l_lp}"`
do
single_char=$(SUBSTR "$col_val" $i)
ascii_num_val=$(ASCII "$single_char")
l_mod=$((l_mod+ascii_num_val))
done
l_mod=$((l_mod % nclsize))
for i in `eval "echo {1..$l_lp}"`
do
single_char=$(SUBSTR "$col_val" $i)
ascii_num_val=$(ASCII "$single_char")
l_an=$ascii_num_val
tempvar=$((l_an - l_lp - l_mod - i))
absnum=$(ABS $tempvar)
if [[ $l_an -ge $austart && $l_an -le $auend ]]; then
tempmodval=$((absnum % aclsize))
tempasciival=$((austart + tempmodval))
l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
elif [[ $l_an -ge $alstart && $l_an -le $alend ]]; then
tempmodval=$((absnum % aclsize))
tempasciival=$((alstart + tempmodval))
l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
elif [[ $l_an -ge $nstart && $l_an -le $nend ]]; then
tempmodval=$((absnum % nclsize))
tempasciival=$((nstart + tempmodval))
l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
else
tempmodval=$((absnum % nclsize))
tempasciival=$((austart + tempmodval))
l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
fi
done
fi
echo "$l_ret_str"
}
```

Here `col_val=$1` entered by user.if user enters 2 then our code will mask second column. we are calling above function through below.

```
    while read p; do
if [[ $line -le $skip_line ]]; then
echo "$p" >> $outputfile
else
pre_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f1-$((colnum - 1))`
column_value=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$colnum`
post_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$((colnum + 1))-$totalcol`
echo "column_value=$column_value"
maskvalue=$(data_mask "$column_value")
echo $pre_str"|"$maskvalue"|"$post_str >> $outputfile
fi
line=$((line + 1))
done <$temp_outputfile
```

Here we are splitting the files in 3 parts. and then calling to our function. here `skipline` is the number of line our code should skip.eg header. 
so if input is

```
id|name|dept
11|Shrut|consultant
12|wipro|HR
13|capgemini|IT
```

then output should be like below.

```
id|name|dept
11|sqmbr|consultant
12|itzaw|HR
13|khvlipkoi|IT
```

Please suggest some way. if you need some clarification I will provide in comment but please dont put it on hold. I have to enhance the speed of execution without changing algorithm written in data_mask(). function can be changed but not the algorithm.
I am expecting your help on the same.

Comment: "Dont put on hold to this question.or downvote. This is exteremely urgent." Just so you know, that is a very good way to get downvoted

Comment: I am really sorry. But me and my colleague just joined few days back and we both have got the same taste many times, thats why I pleaded in advance.

Comment: Just don't. Instead of pleading, you should take a look at [help] and [ask] and read to understand the guidelines of this website. This isn't your personal programming/debugging/optimization service. Don't treat it like that. For the record, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Thanks you @juanpa.arrivillaga . Could you please help me on the same.

Comment: Also : You get _paid_ for this stuff ... shouldnt you be capable of performing the job you take money for?

Comment: I am java developer. Recently  I have been put in this technology. You know the situation of Indian IT industry, to save my job I have to do anything what client want.

Comment: So, rewrite the code in Java, it is much more performant than bash.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am not saying and not expecting someone else do my job. I just want some suggestions. earlier I dint put code here and people criticized and put the question on hold. this time I put the same here

Comment: Dear @Daniel in my new project we have only Oracle and unix. and at the end I can do what client wants. I dont have flexibility to do what I want. I am working for a service provider.

Comment: You can get  lemon juice using a hammer and soap - but I would probably use a lemon press. If your client needs someone that can do unix and bash he should have hired one that can do this. No idea about indian IT business - but if "Service provider" take any contract they do not have qualified ppl to work in it and put anybody available with whatever skill on the job - I am glad I am not in that place and business. I wouldn't take a job I am not qualified for, but I have to luck to have a solid job in what I am good at. Hope you get help, wish you luck - but SO is not the place for it.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it will help, but as it is the code you've posted is practically unreadable without proper indenting. Many people will see that mass of characters and just move on to the next question without even seeing what this one is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash is not very performant doing loops.
Since you tagged the question `python`, python should be ok?

```
def data_mask(col_val):
    mod = len(col_val) + sum(map(ord, col_val)) % 10
    result = ""
    for i, ch in enumerate(col_val, mod + 1):
        absnum = abs(ord(ch) - i)
        if 'A' <= ch <= 'Z':
            ch = chr(ord('A') + absnum % 26)
        elif 'a' <= ch <= 'z':
            ch = chr(ord('a') + absnum % 26)
        elif '0' <= ch <= '9':
            ch = chr(ord('0') + absnum % 10)
        else:
            ch = chr(ord('A') + absnum % 10)
        result += ch
    return result

while open(temp_outputfile) as lines:
    while open(outputfile, 'w') as output:
        output.write(next(lines))
        for line in lines:
            pre, col_val, post = line.split('|', 2)
            output.write("{}|{}|{}".format(pre, data_mask(col_val), post))
```

Comment: Yes it is OK. Thank you so much Daniel.

Answer (score -1):

@ Daniel,
Nice code, has written some thing similar for the same question, 
But since your code was better didn't post mine,
hadn't thought of using enumerate, was looping through them.

Will now go back and rethink a lot of my code to include the freedom of enumerate.

Comment: Thank you so much Apoorv. Thanks for some valuable inputs through offline . It really helped me a lot.

Comment: The above is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @EdMorton, have now learnt how to comment. :)

Comment: great. the next phase in your training will be learning how to delete an answer :-)